# Не устанавливается apk-файл на android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, android-manifest

Собрал приложение, перекинул файл `app-debug.apk` на устройство. При попытке установить этот файл пишет:

```
Синтаксическая ошибка

При синтаксическом анализе пакета возникла ошибка
```

Что интересно, через кнопку `run` в `android studio` все отлично устанавливается и работает.

**В манифесте:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconrectangle"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/roundicon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.blagodari"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Подпиши приложение и сделай релизную сборку

Comment: я еще не доделал его до конца, но мне необходимо продебажить его на разных устройствах

Comment: А причем тут доделал ты его или нет? Я же не говорю выложи в стор. Подпиши временным ключем, при публикации смени если нужно будет. Короче, нужна релизная сборка чтоб не было этих трабл

Comment: хм, попробую, спасибо, но что-то мне кажется, что разницы никакой нет

Comment: @Circassian спасибо, все получилось, но ошибок было 100500, час только исправлял все)

Comment: отлично) Если я смог помочь, поставь галочку на мой ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подпиши приложение

```
Menu -> Build -> Build Signed Bundle / Apk
```